# Histogram of how often actions are played

Tags: netlogo

I have created a model using the Roth-Erev reinforcement learning algorithm so that every round agents select their action `a` from a set of actions `A`. The actions count how often they are played throughout the entire game.

I would now like to create a histogram that has the frequency on the y-axis and the actions on the x-axis. I would also like to label every action with its parameters, but I understand that is not possible.

Merely using `histogram count [n-played] of actions` would not plot every action individually. I think `plotxy` comes closest but isn't suitable for histograms. Is there any build in solution or do I have to visualize data outside of Netlogo?

Comment: are you wanting to show the frequency of actions in the current timestep, totalled over all time to date, or something else? Also, how many actions are there?

Comment: I want to show the summed frequency. There are 27 actions.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to label the columns, but you are not limited to the `histogram` command for producing bar plot. Each plot pen has a [mode](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set-plot-pen-mode) that can be "line", "bar" or "point". By using the "bar" mode, you can produce bar plots with the `plot` or `plotxy` commands:

[image]

Here is the code for easy cut and paste:

```
plot-pen-reset
foreach map [ [ n-played ] of ? ] sort actions plot
```

Note that this uses the "concise task syntax" for passing `plot` to `foreach`. You can write `[ plot ? ]` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful. :-) I've been a little imprecise though. Every action exists for every agent of a breed, so my 27 actions are replicated 5 times. Your code example plots every of those 135 actions, but I want to sum `n-played` of identical actions. To do so I gave them an ID, listed these IDs and used `foreach map [ sum [n-played] of actions with [ id = ?] ] action-id [plot ?]` instead. Unfortunately this yields `MAP expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead.` although action-id is the second thing in the setup procedure and works fine.

Comment: That message indicates that `action-id` is not a list. For your code to work, you'll need to pass a list of unique `action-id`s. If you don't already have one, you can probably generate one with `sort remove-duplicates [ id ] of actions`.